# Dual boot Linux & windows on old mac-book 4.1 without mac OS X installed

Tags: windows, bootable

i changed my HDD that have windows 7 installed to new laptop now i can't boot into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux will boot and run if you swap the drive from another machine, because the kernel is modular, and it custom loads drivers it needs for any specific machine. Windows installs for a certain hardware configuration, and it generally won't work if you swap it out to different hardware.

If you can get it to boot into safe mode, or you boot from the Windows installation DVD, you can run

sfc /scannow

which will add what you need for the changed hardware. But Windows might ask you to register again.

Comment: Thanks for answer , and sorry for being late I was trying it but It doesn’t let me boot to safe mode or any other mode , and unlucky me don’t have the installation dvd.

Comment: yes you are right. my mistake that i was thinking it was about macs devices .